# Draw with custom color without allocation with Xlib

Tags: c, graphics, colors, x11, xlib

I wrote an X "screen driver" for a graphics toolkit project I am working on. My toolkit, as the last step, calls Xlib functions that draw relevant data to screen.

The problem is that, in my toolkit, colors are represented and passed around as 32bit long integers. All the documentation I have read about Xlib resorts to using XAllocColor to define each color in a Colormap.

The problem is, XAllocColor is fairly *slow* compared to my graphics routine and I'd like to avoid alloc'ing each single color used (also because I do not have a list upfront).

How can I draw something in arbitrary colors in Xlib without alloc'ing each and everyone of them?

Comment: Can't remember exactly but you may use DirectColor mode?

Comment: From what I've seen, but I may be wrong, DirectColor is a representation of a color that you anyway have to alloc.

Comment: You're right (my memory failed at it here - no Xlib programming since 20 years), but isn't it some 24 bitmaps mode with TrueColor? (or something like that). I can remember that you can manage the framebuffer to inject 24 bits (provided the display is able to).

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I really can't find a way to do it in code. Every piece of doc I've seen uses XAllocColor.

Comment: As an update, passing an 0xRRGGBB to XSetForeground actually works as expected, even without allocating the color first. Is it luck or, having a non paletted display, all the colors are already available? Mmhh...

Comment: You don't have to allocate colors for TrueColor, StaticColor and StaticGray visuals. The last two should be fairly rare by now, no idea who uses them. TrueColor pixels are RGB values themselves, if you have TrueColor then 0xRRGGBB will indeed work as expected. For DirectColor and PseudoColor, allocate a bunch of colors at a time with XAllocColorCells or XAllocColorPlanes, and store actual pixel values with XStoreColors. Same about GrayScale (hopefully extinct by now).

Comment: Thanks, I believe it could be posted as an answer. I totally overlooked the "visual" concept.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `XColor.pixel` property, it's a long type that contains usually the color in `0xAARRGGBB` (32-bit RGB mode), but that depends on what color mode you use on your X server.